# Are Facebook webhooks failed calls logged somewhere?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks

I read at the Facebook page [Receiving API Updates in Real Time with Webhooks](http://Receiving%20API%20Updates%20in%20Real%20Time%20with%20Webhooks) that,

> If any update sent to your server fails, Facebook will retry again immediately, and then a few more times, with decreasing frequency, over the subsequent 24 hours.

So, what happens if a e.g. hardware or network failure "cuts" the communication between the FB server and my server for more that 24 hours? Users might be posting data in the FB page during the failure, so that means that my side will lose data if it is down for more that 24 hours.

Does the FB server logs somewhere the failed webhooks calls or do i have to rely on myself manually fetching the missed data from the FB server?

Thanks,

CP

Comment: Facebook will attempt to send the data to your server. If you miss any data you will have to fetch it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to go back and query the feed:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/user/feed